# std::vector<std::vector<T>>::end() rend() begin() etc. don't have members?

Tags: c++, clion, bazel

I write this

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
v.rbegin()->push_back({});
```

And IDE says there is no `push_back`. On top of that, there are no members at all, and have no idea why.

**Includes:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
```

> No suggestions for members of std::reverse_iterator

P.S. Use Clion 2018.3 and Bazel

*UPD: Just tried to build the project using CMake. It works! But what can be wrong with Bazel?*

BUILD:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    data = ["open_text.txt"],
)
```

WORKSPACE is empty.

Comment: Please provide [mcve], as text, while including copy-pasted error messages, as text.

Comment: Also, since you actually want to know why CLion can't suggest the members of `std::reverse_iterator`, that information should probably be part of your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Now, it's better

Comment: It is indeed, good fix!

Comment: There is no type `std::reverse_iterator` so `std::reverse_iterator` doesn't _have_ members. It's a template and needs to be instantiated. Seems like a limitation of Clion - have you tried asking on their mailing list?

Comment: You updates have changed this from a question about an IDE to a question about a build system, AFAICT. If you're going to ask about your Bazel build, you probably need to show your compile errors, at least.

Comment: Do you now mean to say that when you change the build system to Bazel, the behaviour of the auto-complete mechanism of the IDE changes? Or did you have a build problem that is now resolved? This is really not clear.

Comment: I mean to say that when I change the build system to CMake, it works like it should: CLion shows possible members as 'push_back' etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're using the CLion IDE, and the Bazel build system, and you are not getting auto-completion in your C++ code. Auto-completion works when you switch to the CMake build system.

Per [the Bazel documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/ide.html), their CLion integration for auto-completion is in *beta*. Clicking through to their IntelliJ docs (via a link under the CLion section) [only Java and Python are listed as supported languages](https://ij.bazel.build/docs/bazel-plugin.html).

So, this is just not supported yet.

You could ask that project's development team for confirmation, and for information on when C++ support may be forthcoming in Bazel for CLion.

By the way, you have a bug in your code: `rbegin()` shall not be dereferenced when the vector is empty. Though hopefully that snippet was just exposition.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh. You have a couple of problems, and it's not entirely obvious which you care about.

1. CLion failing to show `std::reverse_iterator<...>` methods.

   No idea, do you really depend on this?
   There is [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator), you know.
2. Neither the `end()` nor `rend()` iterators are dereferencable anyway, so they don't actually point to *anything*. So even if the *type* your iterator points do has this method, it would be illegal to call because there's no object there.

You can append an element to the last entry in your outer vector like

```
v.back().push_back({});
```

if that's what you want. But, as a final reminder, the `end()` and `rend()` methods return one-past-the-end iterators which may not be dereferenced. Don't do that.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have no idea about the CLion problem. But the code's broken in a couple of separate ways on top of that.

Comment: re #2, the iterator is being dereferenced, producing a vector, which assuredly has a `push_back` member function

Comment: I'm not sure that dereferencing `rend()` counts as producing a vector really - it produces an illegal reference of that type, I guess.

Comment: You're right, but look: there is rbegin() member and there are no options too

Comment: In terms of the type of the expression. We all know the OP shouldn't be dereferencing `rend()`; that does not have any effect on the return type of the relevant `std::reverse_iterator` specialisation's dereference operator, and it does not explain the problem being asked about. Honestly, again, OP should ask the Clion devs.

Comment: Everyone apart from OP presumably knows that, yeah. Anyway, I no longer know whether this is a CLion question that just happens to have an incidental C++ bug, or a Bazel question, or what.

Comment: OP already knows that; we covered it in comments on the other answer where it was confirmed to be unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Return reverse iterator to reverse end Returns a reverse iterator
>   pointing to the theoretical element preceding the first element in the
>   vector (which is considered its reverse end).
>
> The range between vector::rbegin and vector::rend contains all the
>   elements of the vector (in reverse order).

*theoretical element preceding the first* -> It should not be dereferenced. It does not point to an element.

My guess is that you want to do:
`v.back()->push_back({});`

That, given that `v` is not empty. You should do `v.push_back({})` if it's empty as an example, first.

---

As far as the IDE, it should be configuration problem. I mostly work on Eclipse, there this problem is solved usually:

- Setting the compiler settings to match that of your cmake (as an example, C++ projects by default don't come with c++11 enabled, so you should make sure it has a -std=c++11 on the IDE's compiler settings).
- Rescan for all includes.

You usually can try to see if something is not recognized (as an example, understrike on the vector keyword). And when you ctrl+click on vector you could see which header the IDE is using and which code it's using (there might be some ifdefs and some might not be activated, as an example some __cppversion >= 201103L or something like that means the IDE thinks you don't have a C++11 compiler in use).

Comment: True, but irrelevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How's irrelevant? He's asking why he can't have shown by the IDE members on something he should clearly not dereference.

Comment: But there is 'rend()' in the example

Comment: @Mirko You're talking about a logical problem with the program, that has nothing to do with the IDE's ability (or lack thereof) to perform "intellisense" activities on expressions and statements of source code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would first try to correct to something that indeed *can be dereferenced* and then see if the problem persists.

Comment: @DeadAd: Right, and [you should not dereference it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend); perhaps review reverse iterators!

Comment: @Mirko: You're conflating entirely separate problem domains. Code completion will not compile and execute your code to work out whether it has UB because you dereferenced the wrong thing. It looks at the _types_ of expressions and, in that sense, there is nothing wrong with the OP's expectation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know if that IDE doesn't detect that. Again. First, fix it, then retry it would be my first choice. Especially if it's something that causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm telling you that it doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And I'm telling you that I don't know. But it should be fixed anyway. And given two choices: one implies fixing it, the other implies ignoring a problem and taking your word without a source, I would probably first fix what's wrong, and then continue to see if that's true or not.

Comment: You're right, rend() is nonsence here. I've changed it. But, unfortunately, it hasn't solved the problem. And it works if use CMake

Comment: Your edit seems to provide information relating a completely different piece of software?